# Infopath Rules and the "and" condition

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath, rules

I'm trying to create a rule where a field is hidden until FIVE other fields become TRUE. But the hidden field is revealed if any of the 5 conditions becomes true as if I'm using an OR condition. Do "and" conditions not exist in InfoPath rules? See screenshot of my Rule. Thanks

[InfoPath Rule Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx99B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found via another message board I have to use OR instead of AND even though it seems like they should be AND conditions. I have 37 conditions now all with OR between them and the hidden section does not appear until all 30 conditions are TRUE now. Whatever works, I guess :)

[Rule Conditions using OR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHjmf.png)